# Ruby on Rails externalising Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm primarily a LAMP developer that is slowly making the switch to ruby development. In PHP, I can split the page into segments (to maximise code re-use) using separate PHP files for each section. An example of this being wordpress, where you have a separate header / sidebar / content file etc.

Is this possible using Ruby on Rails? Would it be the equivalent of embedding a controller / view into another view? So far i'm a bit stumped on the way anything would be embedded because it seems there is a controller that has a route for a view, so i'm unsure as to which bit you would try include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are called `partials`. You can create a partial, such as a sidebar or a footer, then render it into a template.

The official Rails guide contains some information about [using partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Essentially, you create a file name prefixed by an underscore such as `posts/_form.html.erb` and you render it into the view

```
<%= render partial: "form" %>
```

You can also specify an absolute path from the `views` folder

```
<%= render partial: "/posts/form" %>
```

The same naming conventions of the template (e.g. the format suffixes) apply.

Comment: Just tried this, it worked perfectly, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented sidebar using partials. Hope this will answers the most part of your question.

First, edit **application_controller.rb** to pass variables to layout view. Use **before_action**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_page

  def set_page
    @categories = Category.all
  end

end
```

next, edit layout view(**application.html.erb**)

```
<body>
  <div class="container">     
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <%= render partial: 'categories/sidebar' %>
    </div>                 
  </div>
</body>
```

then create partial. You can directory access controller variables from the partial.
**/views/categories/_sidebar.html.erb**

```
<h3>Categories</h3>
<div class="row">
  <br> 
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
       <h5 class="media-heading">
         <%= link_to category.name, category %>
       </h5>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

For page screenshot and more detail, checkout [my post](http://www.letmefix-it.com/2017/07/24/create-sidebar-using-partials-ruby-on-rails/).

Comment: (Nice example, but the question is from 1.5 yrs ago, and seems as though it was answered?)